# Mulesoft Java Transformer

Tags: java, spring

I have no clue how to use a Java Transformer in Mulesoft. I want to basically take a String and convert it to a URL, but I cannot figure out how to use the Java method or anything.

What am I doing wrong? How can I take I call my method, or make it so that my method is used with the value I want it to be?

**ERRORS:**

> org.mule.module.launcher.DeploymentInitException:
>   IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [transformers.StringTransformer] to required type
>   [org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessor] for property
>   'messageProcessors[4]': no matching editors or conversion strategy
>   found
>
> Caused by: org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException: Error creating
>   bean with name 'streamMigrateAccountToCustomer': Initialization of
>   bean failed; nested exception is
>   org.springframework.beans.ConversionNotSupportedException: Failed to
>   convert property value of type [java.util.ArrayList] to required type
>   [java.util.List] for property 'messageProcessors'; nested exception is
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Cannot convert value of type
>   [transformers.StringTransformer] to required type
>   [org.mule.api.processor.MessageProcessor] for property
>   'messageProcessors[4]': no matching editors or conversion strategy
>   found (org.mule.api.lifecycle.InitialisationException)
>   (org.mule.api.config.ConfigurationException)

**StringTransformer**

```
@ContainsTransformerMethods
public class StringTransformer
{
    public String website;

  public String getWebsite() {
      return website;
  }

  public void setWebsite(String website) {
      this.website = website;
  }

@Transformer
  public String stringToURL(String string) throws MalformedURLException
  {
      return new java.net.URL(string).toString();
  }
}
```

**XML**

```
<custom-transformer class="transformers.StringTransformer" doc:name="Java">
    <spring:property name="website" value="#[payload.Website]"/>
</custom-transformer>
```

**INPUT TO JAVA TRANSFORMER**

```
%dw 1.0
%output application/java
---
{
    Id: payload.Id,
    Name: payload.Name,
    Active_CMRR__c: payload.Active_CMRR__c,
    BillingStreet: payload.BillingStreet,
    BillingCity: payload.BillingCity,
    BillingState: payload.BillingState,
    BillingPostalCode: payload.BillingPostalCode,
    BillingCountry: payload.BillingCountry,
    OwnerId: payload.OwnerId,
    Website: payload.Website,
    Contract_End_Date__c: payload.Contract_End_Date__c,
    NS_Account_Number__c: payload.NS_Account_Number__c,
    Phone: payload.Phone,
    Subscription_Start_Date__c: payload.Subscription_Start_Date__c,
    NS_Account_Name__c: payload.NS_Account_Name__c,
    type: payload.type,
    Owner: {
        NS_Account_Manager_Id__c: payload.Owner.NS_Account_Manager_Id__c,
        Id: payload.Owner.Id,
        type: payload.Owner.type,
        Name: payload.Owner.Name
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For a simple string manipulation I prefer to use a simple MEL expression, heres an example of creating a new variable.

```
<set-variable variableName="website" value="#[new java.net.URL(payload.Website).toString()]" doc:name="Variable"/>
```

To do a [java transformations](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.8/creating-custom-transformer-classes) on the MuleMessage, I prefer to extend the AbstractMessageTransformer class.

```
public class ExampleAbstractMessageTransformer extends AbstractMessageTransformer {

@Override
public Object transformMessage(MuleMessage message, String outputEncoding) throws TransformerException  {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    HashMap<String, String> payload = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String websiteUrl = new String();

    //Grab Payload
    payload = (HashMap<String, String>) message.getPayload();
    try {
        websiteUrl = stringToURL(payload.get("Website").toString());
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    message.setInvocationProperty("websiteUrl", websiteUrl);
    return message;
}

public String stringToURL(String string) throws MalformedURLException {
    return new java.net.URL(string).toString();
}
}
```

Implementing within the Mulesoft flow. Assuming the java code is packaged as com.stackoverflow.transformers utilize the "custom-transformer" component.

```
<custom-transformer class="com.stackoverflow.transformers.ExampleAbstractMessageTransformer" doc:name="Java" />
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use invoke component to call java method. check https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/invoke-component-reference

Comment: Please explain *how* to do that in the answer itself.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ContainsTransformerMethods // since Mule 3.0.1 
    public class MyTransformers {  
    @Transformer  
    public URL stringToURL(String string) {  
       return new java.net.URL(string); 
    }
    @Transformer 
    public List<URL> stringsToURLs(String string) {    
       List<URL urls = new ArrayList<URL>();   
       for (StringTokenizer tokenizer = new StringTokenizer(string); tokenizer.hasMoreTokens();) {       
          urls.add(new URL(tokenizer.nextToken()));
       }   
       return urls;
    }
 }
```

Comment: Try to explain your answer. Don't just give the code as the answer